# TFS command line to get list of files checked in yesterday

Tags: command-line

I'm looking for a simple way to get a list of files that were checked in on a certain day.  Is there a command line I can use?  I don't want changesets just the file names.

Comment: The database is another place you can look into. It is very useful for us to get lists of changes / checkins after a certain date.

Comment: @StingyJack: Is using database directly a good way? Database structures may change over new versions of TFS.

Comment: @afsharm - Yes, that is true, but future plans are future guesses. Database queries are simple to maintain.

Answer (score 9):

A bit late, but for others asking the same question.

Open a *Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)* and use the command:

```
tf history "local path" /version:D2011-03-29 /recursive /noprompt
```

Replace the date with the date you wan't information about and localpath to the local folder you bound to, you WILL get the changeset number, but also all items changes. It's also possible to use a collection and remote path instead of local path.

Naturally you can discard noprompt and login and put in that information in a prompt.

More information about the TFS 2010 commandline: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx

Answer (score -4):

Use [`tf` command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx). It may do what ever you want.

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example that is actually useful?